# Numba - @generated_jit returns "complex object has no attribute 'real' "

Tags: python, numba, complex-numbers

```
from numba import generated_jit

@generated_jit
def get_max_num(z, max_iter, c, func, mandelbrot=False):
    if mandelbrot:
        temp = z
        z = c
        c = temp
    result = 0
    while z.real ** 2 + z.imag ** 2 <= 4 and result < max_iter:
        z = func(z, c)
        result += 1

    return result
```

`z` and `c` are complex numbers.
`func` is a lambda function.
`max_iter` is an int.
`mandelbrot` is a boolean.

The code above returns `AttributeError: 'Complex' object has no attribute 'real'`.
This behavior doesn't seem to happen with the `@jit` decorator which is used in like it happens with `@generated_jit`.

Comment: `@generated_jit` is used to dispatch a function in different ways depending on its input types. The function that you decorate with `@generated_jit` is actually fed the *types* of the inputs (like the `Complex` type that's confusing you), rather than the inputs themselves, and then the function is supposed to return another function that actually does the execution. See [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/generated-jit.html). This looks like an example where you should just be using `@jit`?

Comment: @macroeconomist Thank you but as far as i know '@jit' doesn't support lambda functions and from what i found only '@generated_jit' does.